# As programmers do we have to care about struct padding in the context of pointers to struct?

Tags: c, pointers, struct, padding

I've used pointers in C for some time now and they have always worked as expected. However now I've run into a book that asserts this in the context of C struct padding and pointers : "Several implications are related to this allocation of extra memory:

- Pointer arithmetic must be used with care
- Arrays of structures may have extra memory between their elements"

Consider all this code that uses structs ( with padding ) and pointers in various ways. It works perfectly fine :

```
//struct Test is 8 Bytes in size ( 2 extra Bytes padding ) 

struct Test{

    int a;
    char b;

};

struct Test t1;
t1.a = 20;
t1.b = 'D';

struct Test t2;
t1.a = 40;
t1.b = 'H';

//creating a pointer to a struct Test variable

struct Test *p = &t1;
(*p).a = 50;

//creating an array of struct Test objects

struct Test arr[] = {t1, t2};
p = arr;

//using pointer arithmetic with p :

(*(p+1)).a = 100;

//creating an array of struct Test pointers

struct Test* pt1 = &t1;
struct Test* pt2 = &t2;
struct Test* arr2[] = {pt1, pt2};

(*(*(arr2 + 1))).a = 300;

//creating an array of struct Test pointers pointing to struct Test pointers :

struct Test t3;
t3.a = 56;
t3.b = 'J';
struct Test t4;
t4.a = 221;
t4.b = 'L';

struct Test* pt3 = &t3;
struct Test* pt4 = &t4;
struct Test* arr3[] = {pt3, pt4};
struct Test** arr4[] = {arr2, arr3};

(*(*(*(arr4 + 1)))).a = 400;
```

Everything works fine even if there's padding. I'm assuming that as programmers we don't have to worry about struct and paddings...so my questions are :

1. What does the book is trying to warn us against ?
2. Do we programmers have to care about struct and paddings in the context of pointers and also in other contexts in general ?

Comment: Does the book have any additional context for how or why this could be an issue? It can be for cross platform code where types are different sizes, like `long` on Windows versus Linux and others. `sizeof(struct)` includes any padding and normal pointer arithmetic also takes this into account.

Comment: >other contexts< if you handle network packets, there's a lot of places where you have to take into account paddings

Comment: Yeah, definitely for serialization/deserialization.

Comment: Normally, the compiler will choose padding so that the programmer doesn't have to worry about such things, but it is something the programmer should be aware of, especially alignment issues when packing structs or dynamically allocating structs with exotic types in them like __int128 or __m256. Also, choosing a space efficient ordering of the elements should be something the programmer should care about, but that's a separate issue.

Comment: Arrays never contain "extra memory" (or padding) between elements. The offset in bytes between consecutive elements is always the size of one element. The size of one element as measured by the `sizeof` operator includes any padding within that element. Within a struct type object, there may be padding between members and after the last member, but never before the first member.

Comment: Generally, if you are working on embedded systems or transferring data between programs or have very large arrays, worry about it a little.  If it is all within one program on a PC/mainframe and your arrays aren't big, don't lose any sleep over it.  You don't need to slave for hours to save 100 bytes on a 4Gb-8Gb machine.

Answer (score 1):

> However now I've run into a book…

Cite the book.

> … that asserts this in the context of C struct padding and pointers : "Several implications are related to this allocation of extra memory:
>
> - Pointer arithmetic must be used with care
> - Arrays of structures may have extra memory between their elements"

The latter is technically incorrect. A structure may have padding between its members and at the end, and this is considered part of the structure. When an array is created, there is no additional padding between the elements of the array, only the padding inside the structures, including the padding at their ends.

The former is vague and useless.

The example code you show uses only pointers to structures. Concerns about memory layout related to padding apply to accessing members of structures and the bytes that represent structures. Since a structure may have padding between its members, you cannot assume that, if one member is at offset O from the start of the structure and has size S, then the next member will start at offset O+S. It may start at some offset O+S+P, where P is the number of padding bytes the C implementation uses between them.

Typical C implementations will use just enough padding to make O+S+P a multiple of the alignment requirement of the next member. For example, if O is 0 (for the first member of the structure), S is 1 (because the member is a `char` perhaps), and the next member is an `int` with alignment requirement four bytes, then P will be 3 so that O+S+P is 4, a multiple of the needed alignment. The padding at the end will also be calculated to make the total structure size a multiple of the strictest alignment of the members, so that all members remain aligned when the structure is used in an array.

One concern a programmer might have about padding in structures is how much space the structure uses. If the members are laid out inefficiently, a structure may have more padding than necessary, and, if a program uses a great many instances of the structure, it may use more memory than necessary. To reduce memory use, in the definition of the structure, order the members with the strictest alignment requirements first.

Concerns about padding layout may also arise when the memory representing a structure is accessed in other ways, such as using multiple different structures in a union or when transmitting or storing bytes for reinterpretation by other software.

The former, using the same memory as different types of structures (or different types generally), should be avoided and, when not avoidable, must be used judiciously and with knowledge about the rules of C and the C implementations being used.

The latter also requires particular knowledge and care. One approach to exchanging data between different software (including the same source code compiled for different target platforms) is to define a specific format for representing the data and converting data from C types to that format as it is written and converting in the reverse direction when it is read. This can be done in ways that are agnostic to the representations of types in C with sufficient care and knowledge, but it can be cumbersome. Programmers might try to take shortcuts and use the memory contents of structures more directly. In those circumstances, you need to care about padding, as well as issues about how data is represented, such as endianness.

Comment: Eric Postpischil, as you pointed out using pointers to struct fields could be dangerous because of padding. For example if have struct Test{ int a, char b} we are not guaranteed that b can be simply accessed at &a + 4 ( because of padding ). However is it always correct to access a struct field with a pointer like : struct Test t1; int* p = &(t1.a); and then doing *p ? Is this gonna have predictable and safe result ?

Comment: @alessiosolari: Yes. And, once again, cite the book. Anytime anybody posts to Stack Overflow with a question about something they read in some book, they should give a bibliographic citation for the book, including the page and/or section number, so that other people can refer to the original material and interpret it in context.

Comment: The book is Understanding and Using C Pointers by Richard Reese

Comment: While I am at it I want to point out what is also suggested in the book that seems to contradict a bit what you confirmed in the last comment. The book creates typedef struct _item { int partNumber; int quantity; int binNumber}Item;
and it says that we shouldn't assume ( as you said ) that for example we can access quantity at &partNumber + 4. However then it also says that a "better approach" is to do something like int *pi = &part.partNumber. But the it continues and says "Even better, do not use pointers at all" and do part.partNumber". Why is it do not use pointers at all ? Is it wrong ?

Comment: @alessiosolari You can use the `offsetof(type, member)` macro (`#include <stddef.h>`)to determine the byte offset of a member from the start of the struct. For example, `offsetof(struct Test, b)`.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer no, you don't need to learn about the struct padding.
the reason why C adds some padding is for performance reason, although you can disable it (not recommended) if you are on a strict memory by adding `#pragma pack(1)` on the top of your file to set one byte boundaries.

Comment: redouane, but what about padding in the context of struct pointers ? Is there something that I shouldn't do when dealing with pointers in the context of C struct ?

Answer (score -1):

Consider this:
from one side of network there's a sender on raspberrypi 32bit with compiled `struct data { char c; long num;};` (sizeof(struct data) is 8bytes) and sending `{ .c = 'a', .num = 1 }`,
and a receiver on 64bit PC on the other side with the same unpacked struct (i.e. sizeof(struct data) is 16bytes).
What will a receiver have in .num?